# Каким способом можно переписать данный код в отдельный класс, чтобы потом использовать неоднократное количество раз?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Данный код полностью работает по нажатию на `button`, но мне необходимо вынести в отдельный класс, т.к. кнопка будет не одна. На выходе хочу получить то, что буду вызывать метод, а в нем указывать SQL-запрос для выполнения. Надеюсь, все ясно разъяснил.

```
string connString = @"Data Source=LEEDOQUE\PORTLAND; Initial Catalog=MyCompany; Integrated Security=True";

try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        string query = @"SELECT * FROM [MyCompany].[dbo].[Users]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dAdapter.Fill(ds);
        Table.ReadOnly = true;
        Table.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        conn.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```

Строка подключения в app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="cnstr" 
         connectionString="Data Source=LEEDOQUE\PORTLAND; Initial Catalog=MyCompany; Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Класс подключения:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    protected SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnstr"].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Условно будет метод `public void GetData(string Connection)`, в данный метод передаем `string Connection`, но вторым параметром должна быть строка подключения, верно?

Comment: Вы не в комментарий, а в вопрос добавляйте. https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/11.php

Comment: Как потом работать с репозиторием, если нужно буду выполнять процедуры по добавлению, обновлению и удалению данных?

Comment: Там всё написано. Или возьмите Entity Framework. В нём уже всё реализовано.

Comment: Не обязательно принимать ответ, если пока не получается применить его на практике. Можно задать другие вопросы (новые темы), чтобы решить попутные проблемы, а потом вернуться к этому, даже через неделю или больше. Но если ответ помог, то здорово.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш класс может выглядеть примерно так:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    private readonly string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnstr"].ConnectionString;

    public DataTable GetData(string sqlQuery)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
        using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Используйте его так:

```
var dataAccess = new DataAccess();
string query = @"SELECT * FROM [MyCompany].[dbo].[Users]";
var dataTable = dataAccess.GetData(query);
```

Comment: @IvanLabozhevich - вы для чего вопрос задавали? Чтобы игнорировать ответы? Вы хотели отдельный класс с методом, возвращающим данные. Вот он, берите, используйте. Нет, вместо этого вы опять пишете рукопашный код.

Comment: @IvanLabozhevich - `new Pages.MainPage()` - это создаёт **новую** форму. Вам именно это надо? Тогда сделайте `mainPage.Show()`. Однако, полагаю, вам нужно на уже **существующей** форме сделать привязку данных. PS: не пишите код в комментариях; не задавайте вопросы в комментариях - создайте новую тему.