# Переписать данный метод для неоднократного использования

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Метод `Name` необходимо прописывать каждый раз, чтобы вызвать нужную процедуру, которую заранее создал c помощью `SQL`. Cуть вопроса в том: как переписать данный метод, чтобы я мог вызвать данный метод и указать нужную процедуру? Хотелось бы видеть примерно так: `void name(procedure)`, но при этом, чтобы данные всегда отображались после изменения в `DataGridView`.

`Table` в коде - это `DataGridView`

```
 public class ShowDataGrid: DataAccess
{
    public DataGridView GetData(string procedureName, DataGridView Data)
    {
        using (var connection = GetConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(procedureName, connection);
                dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                Data.DataSource = dataTable;
                Data.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            }
        }
        return Data;
    }
}
```

Использование метода:

```
Connections.ShowDataGrid show = new Connections.ShowDataGrid();
Show.GetData("ViewUsers", Table);
```

Я хочу вынести данный метод в класс, а потом вызвать его, но при это указывать название процедуры `SQL`, чтобы каждый раз не переписывать код:
Пример: есть у меня `button`, а в нем я вызываю метод `var xxx  = DataAccess.Name(Procedure SQL)`

Comment: Какой тип возвращают все эти хранимки? Это всегда скаляр?

Comment: Да, всегда скалярная величина.

Comment: вам оказывается уже [отвечали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/984781/179763) на этот вопрос и дали ответ, текущий абсолютно такой же. никаких отличий нет. вы понимаете, что вам дают один и тот же ответ? У вас проблемы с тем, что вы не понимаете, как применить этот ответ или вы не можете сформулировать точно, что вам нужно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Каким способом можно переписать данный код в отдельный класс, чтобы потом использовать неоднократное количество раз?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/984486/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be

Comment: Тот вариант не решил моих проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже вам даже [параметризация](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.9.php) не нужна:

```
void Name(string procedureName)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(procedureName, mysqlCon);
        sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dTable);
        Table.DataSource = dTable;
        Table.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Или я чего-то не понимаю в задаче? Это же самые основы языка — параметры функций.

Comment: Я тоже не понимаю, автору уже [советовали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/984781/179763) что то похожее

Comment: @tym32167 в текущем виде вопрос полный дубликат.